# Import text files contents and name of text file into Excel with a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code below which partially works.

- Cats.txt (Contents: grey, blue, black)
- Dogs.txt (Contents: pink, red, orange)
- Cow.txt (Contents: black, white)

This is what I would like to get:

[image]

```
Dim objFSO    As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile   As Object
Dim strPath   As String
Dim strName   As String

' Specify the folder...
strPath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\TEST\"
' Use Microsoft Scripting runtime.
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
' Check extension of each file in folder.
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
If Right(objFile.Name, 4) = ".txt" Then
Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name

    i = i + 1

End If
End Sub
```

Unfortunately I am unable to get the contents of the text file imported into column B. I have been looking online that I am a little bit unsuccessful to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. Make sure you add the reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" ...

```
Option Explicit

Sub load()

    ' ADD REFERENCE TO MICROSOFT FILE SYSTEM OBJECT

    Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim objFile As File
    Dim objTextStream As TextStream
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' Specify the folder...
    strPath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\TEST\"

    ' Use Microsoft Scripting runtime.
    Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)

    ' Check extension of each file in folder.
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "txt" Then
            Cells(i + 1, 1) = objFile.Name
            Set objTextStream = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
            Cells(i + 1, 2) = objTextStream.ReadAll
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you,  Set objTextStream = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
            Cells(i + 1, 2) = objTextStream.ReadAll    So this is the key part.

Comment: hello, just in case you are interested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61986786/import-text-files-contents-and-name-of-text-file-and-you-separator-into-excel-wi