# Import text files contents and name of text file and you separator into Excel with a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code thanks to [Import text files contents and name of text file into Excel with a macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61945419/import-text-files-contents-and-name-of-text-file-into-excel-with-a-macro/61945744#61945744)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Import_video_txt_files()

    ' ADD REFERENCE TO MICROSOFT FILE SYSTEM OBJECT

    Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder As folder
    Dim objFile As file
    Dim objTextStream As TextStream
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' Specify the folder...
    strPath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\TEST\"

    ' Use Microsoft Scripting runtime.
    Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)

    ' Check extension of each file in folder.
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "txt" Then
            Cells(i + 2, 1) = objFile.Name
            Set objTextStream = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
            Cells(i + 2, 2) = objTextStream.ReadAll
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

However now I need to expand the function.

The text file has all the information on one line.

For example: **grey, red, blue|408.95|14165.849841859**

I am using this separator **|**

I would like to be able to import all the information from the text file and separate them using **|** and put them in their appropriate cells as illustrated in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
Sub Import_video_txt_files()

    ' ADD REFERENCE TO MICROSOFT FILE SYSTEM OBJECT

    Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder As folder
    Dim objFile As file
    Dim objTextStream As TextStream
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s As String, vSplit

    ' Specify the folder...
    strPath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\TEST\"

    ' Use Microsoft Scripting runtime.
    Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)

    ' Check extension of each file in folder.
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "txt" Then
            Cells(i + 2, 1) = objFile.Name
            Set objTextStream = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
            'Cells(i + 2, 2) = objTextStream.ReadAll
            s = objTextStream.ReadAll
            vSplit = Split(s, "|")
            Range("b" & i + 2).Resize(1, UBound(vSplit) + 1) = vSplit
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked perfectly. One thing if I may. When I import it, the last part "column D" has a line break. is there a way to remove than please. Thank you

Comment: @Arthor You can use `Replace` VBA Function like that `s = Replace(objTextStream.ReadAll, vbCrLf, vbNullString)`.

Comment: @YasserKhalil - Thank you. this is good to remember for the future.

Comment: @Dy.Lee Hello, I just wanted to know where I would add to the code to only look for files names that have Comp_1. For example, TEST_User_Comp1, Test_Call_Comp2, Test_try_Comp1. In this case only two txt files will be accepted. Thank you

Comment: @Arthor, Add another if statement. `If InStr(objFile.Name, "Comp_ 1") Then`

Comment: @Dy.Lee FYI. This is what I have:  ```If objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name) = "txt" And InStr(objFile.Name, "Comp_1") Then``` Thank you

Answer (score 1):

After importing your pipe data, run this short macro:

```
Sub PipeKleaner()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, s As String, arr
    Dim v As String

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To N
        v = Cells(i, "B").Value
        arr = Split(v, "|")
        Cells(i, "C").Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
    Next i
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

This code does the parsing into column **C** and beyond rather than over-writing column **B**.  If you don't need the original data, just change the `Resize()` code-line.